# MySql UUID Byte Order

Tags: mysql, mysql-connector

I have a MySql table in which the primary key is an auto-increment column and then I also have a `binary(16)` column with a unique index for storing UUIDs.

The `MySqlConnector` has a connection option for `GuidFormat` in which, I'm confused between `TimeSwapBinary16` and `LittleEndianBinary16` in terms of which one of these would be a better choice and why.

Does the arrangement of UUID bytes in a certain order provide benefit when it comes to efficiency and performance such as during insertions, indexing, selecting with the `binary(16)` column in a `WHERE` clause etc?

Can someone please explain these?

Comment: Please add to your question what your criteria are for selecting one of the two settings. One is not better than the other one, unless you add a criteria to your decision. The question is "a better choice for what?".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a general principle that inserting new values to an index in ascending order results in a moderately more efficient index.

While the default UUID format for MySQL includes bytes generated from the timestamp, they are not in a byte position within the UUID that makes it conform to the "insert in ascending order" goal. In MySQL 8.0, they introduced a function `UUID_TO_BIN()` which has an option to rearrange the bytes so that as you generate UUID values, they are ordered by timestamp.

The `TimeSwapBinary16` connector option employs that option, so it is better for index insertion performance.

The performance difference between non-ordered and ordered UUID's is shown with detailed benchmarks in this blog post, if you're interested: https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/12/19/store-uuid-optimized-way/